# How to create a slug route excluding some slug in laravel routing?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, slug

I've following routes currently.

```
$router->get('/contact-us','HomeController@contactUs')->name('contact-us');
$router->get('/about','HomeController@about')->name('about');
```

Now, I want to make general pages accessible form following route,

```
$router->get('/{slug}','SomeController@about')->name('general-page');
```

But main problem is contact us and about page matched with slug route and wrong controller is called. Is there any way to exclude such slugs from general page route.

Comment: Try to change their order. Something like that worked for me while a go

Comment: Just add a prefix to one of them. you cant have two routes but with the same path.

Comment: @ijubadr So slug route should be after contact us and about routes ?

Comment: I remember using catch all route, and I placed it at the bottom

Comment: And clear route cache if you cached at any point

Comment: It should be your last route definition. I have a similar setup.

Comment: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: placing slug route at the end works for me. Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a pattern to your route, where the terms `contact-us` and `about` are excluded, like this:

```
$router->get('/{slug}','SomeController@about')
    ->where('slug', '^((?!about|contact-us).)*$')
    ->name('general-page');
```

For an explanation of the regex, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/4593376)

In this way the order of the route definitions has no consequence.